# Faster conversion of pandas columns based on column values than iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion

I have event stream:

```
unixtimestamp, eventname, type Array<>, value Array<>
1595235332848,event1, ['Boolean','Boolean'], ['True','['True','False']']
1595235333254,event1, ['Boolean','Boolean'], ['True','['True','True']']
1595235333785,event2, ['Float64','Float64'], ['0.0','123.12323']
```

In the beginning, everything is of type str or an array of strings. I use pivot table to construct a huge table (~18k columns, >1 mio. rows):

```
def aggfunc(self, x):
    value_str = ' '.join(str(y) for x in np.unique(x.values) for y in x)
    return value_str
pivot_df = data_df.pivot_table(values=['value', 'type'],index=['unixtimestamp'], columns=['eventname'], aggfunc=self.aggfunc)
#Gives me two DFs DF['value'] and DF['type'] with all columns
print(pivot_df.shape)
conversion_arr = {}
typings_to_python_types_arr = {'Boolean': 'bool', 'Byte': 'bytes', 'ByteString': 'bytes', 'DateTime': 'datetime64[ns]', 'Double': 'float64', 'Float': 'float64', 'Int16': 'int16', 'Int32': 'int32', 'Int64': 'int64', 'SByte': 'str', 'String': 'str', 'UInt16': 'uint16', 'UInt32': 'uint32' }
for column in pivot_df['type'].columns:
      conversion_arr[column] = typings_to_python_types_arr [pivot_df['type'][column].unique()[0]]
pivot_df['value'].astype(conversion_arr)
```

At the moment, I create a to-cast dict in an iterative manner, which is slow as hell for 6k columns. It takes about 5 min. I use the first unique element of the type series and set that as the python type for the corresponding column. Afterward, I cast the huge table at once, which is fast. But, the iteration over all columns/uniqueness calls is taking so much time. Any chance to speed the procedure up?

P.S: There is also a pitty in my aggfunc, that if there are different non-identical values, a space-separated string is created, which crashes the conversion. Any additional ideas on this additional issue are welcomed.

Edit://
Expected output, which would be nice:

```
unixtimestamp,  event1/value,  event2/value
1595235332848, [(dtype boolean)True, (dtype list(boolean))[True, False]], NaN
1595235333254, [(dtype boolean)True, (dtype list(boolean))[True, True ]], NaN
1595235333785, NaN                                                      , [(dtype float64)0.0, (dtype float64)123.12323]
```

or the best would be an unpacked version:

```
unixtimestamp,  event1/value,  event2/value
1595235332848, [(dtype boolean)True, (dtype boolean)True, (dtype boolean)False], NaN
1595235333254, [(dtype boolean)True, (dtype boolean)True, (dtype boolean)True ], NaN
1595235333785,  NaN                                                            , [(dtype float64)0.0, (dtype float64)123.12323]
```

Comment: Can you give code that creates your input dataframe and also, the expected output from this sample input?

Comment: You say you _"use the first unique element of the type series"_ - you're using `np.unique(x.values)` and `pivot_df['type'][column].unique()[0]` which means it needs to first go through >1 mil entries x 18k times, twice. Maybe fewer iterations on the pivoted df. Consider reducing that to taking just the 1st non-null, non-NA or non-trivial value. Doing that 18k times shouldn't be that slow.

Comment: pivot_table function is fast, because the np.unique() is called on series < 10. That's not the problem. The problem is time-intensive the for-loop over the type columns to create the conversion_arr.

Comment: @Scott Boston added example output. Atm, I cannot provide you with a generator function sorry. I have to write one, later.

Comment: Am I missing something when I think the typecasting can be done when reading the data? When you iterate over the source, be it a file or a network socket, you can do the cleaning/typecasting without adding an extra loop. I'd wrap it in a generator.

Comment: What I need would be a conditional cast in the aggfunc, because of the aggfunc everything is str and the problem arise in the end. A cast, in the beginning, is not helpful because of the aggfunc everything is str again. Otherwise, I do not know how to merge values of different types together without concat to a str. A conditional cast would be more helpful is it possible to access other parts of the row in the aggfunc?